# Paypal keeps on asking to create new account when paying using credit card

Tags: paypal

Is this the real behavior of Paypal. I am using the Paypal REST api (payment api's), and it is working fine and customers can use it. The only problem is when a new customer (one that has not visited paypal.com once) tries to buy our product, paypal seems to require him to create an account.

Here's the procedure:

1. First time to visit paypal.com (meaning no cookies / not cached or anything).
2. Customer Buy Product (Our website creates the payment transaction then redirects him to paypal.com)
3. Customer click Pay with my credit or debit card (He does not want to create a paypal account).
4. The country set is Philippines (I think paypal detects this so it is initially set to where I am) and I can proceed paying with my credit card
5. I tried changing the country to somewhere else
6. Here's comes the problem, on some countries, I am shown a different form, a form for creating a new account in Paypal.

Hope you understand what I am saying. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.techycommerce.com/account-optional/

Comment: That was fast. Thanks for the link. will inform the team regarding this settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s important to remember that guest checkout is not guaranteed for every transaction. PayPal runs a risk check to determine eligibility for guest checkout. There will be times when guest checkout is not available. This is intended. Here are a few things to make sure guest checkout is offered as often as possible.

-Verified PayPal account

-Confirmed email address

-Guest Checkout enabled -  To see this, log in, go to Profile and click 'My selling preferences', click on Update next to Website preferences - scroll down the screen and find "PayPal Account Optional" section - you can enable/disable PayPal Account optional here.

-With Express Checkout their cart must pass “SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole”

Unfortunately, there are few parameters which are still incompatible with REST API including `SOLUTIONTYPE` which works only in Classic API.

If all of these are met and it’s not available then our system has decided to disable the guest checkout option for risk reasons. This is not a permanent decision and it will be available in the future.